# Rudin's Definition of Ordered Fields

Tags: ordered-fields

In his *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Rudin defines ordered fields as follows:

An *ordered field* is a field $F$ which is also an *order set*, such that

(i) $x+y<x+z$ if $x, y, z\in F$ and $y<z$,

(ii) $xy>0$ if $x\in F$, $y\in F$, $x>0$, and $y>0$.

In the above definition, is it necessary to explicitly require for the order on $F$ to satisfy these two conditions? In other words, is it possible to have a field with an order such that (i) and (ii) do not hold?

Rudin defines orders as follows:

Let $S$ be a set. An *order* on $S$ is a relation, denoted by $<$, with the following two properties:

(iii)If $x\in S$ and $y\in S$ then one and only one of the statements $$x<y, ~~x=y,~~ y<x$$ is true.

(iv) If $x, y, z\in S$, if $x<y$ and $y<z$, then $x<z$.

Comment: Yes, the point is that the order interacts "nicely" with the field operations. It is easy to exhibit fields that are not ordered fields and admit an order. For instance, any finite field, or $\mathbb C$.

Comment: So do (i) and (ii) not automatically follow from (iii) and (iv)?

Comment: (iii) and (iv) don't say anything about $+$ or $\times$. It would be really surprising if they were related. Really, I think that once you realize how many completely different linear orderings can be given to a set you will see how unlikely it is to expect such a relation. Or, put another way, how special an order on a field has to be to be compatible with the field operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example to demonstrate that a field together with an ordering on the underlying set is not automatically an ordered field.

The field is $\Bbb R$ with usual addition and multiplication.

The ordering is as follows. Let $\ll$ denote the following relation: $x \ll y$ if $x$ and $y$ are both rational and $x<y$ by the usual order, or if $x$ and $y$ are both irrational and $x<y$ by the usual order, or if $x$ is rational and $y$ is irrational.

In this order, we have both $\pi \gg 0$ and $-\pi \gg 0$, but their sum is not $\gg 0$.